# Specify per stream/table timestamp extractor in Kafka Streams using the Stream DSL

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'd like to join two different topics using Kafka Streams. The two topic has its data in different formats, so I'd like to use different timestamp extractors. I saw that there was a merged pullrequest for this feature ([KAFKA-4144](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4144)), but I [only find it](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html#addSource(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) for the Processor API.

Does this feature exist for the Stream API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StreamsBuilder#stream(...)` has an overload taking a `Consumed` parameter that allows you to specify all optional properties like timestamp extractor.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/Consumed.html

In general, you can find API changes describes in the upgrade guide:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#api-changes
- https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/upgrade-guide#streams_api_changes_100